# How do I adapt an old C style #define mapping with modern C++?

Tags: c++

In an old C header file, I have the following mapping (32 lines long):

```
#define    IOCON_INDEX_PIO0_17       ( 0)
#define    IOCON_INDEX_PIO0_13       ( 1)
#define    IOCON_INDEX_PIO0_12       ( 2)
//...
```

In C++ I could have a function that takes an index and returns an int. To do so I would initialize an array in only one line, but it wouldn't be very much readable.

I would like to replace it with C++ with a modern styling.
I have thought to something using lambdas like this:

```
#include <array>
class test 
{
    int icon_index(int pio_index)
    {
        const std::array<int, 32> iocon_index = [](){
            std::array<int, 32> buf;
            buf[17] = 0;
            buf[13] = 1;
            buf[12] = 2;
            //...
            return buf;
        }();
        return iocon_index[pio_index];
    }
};
```

But when I look to the [assembly generated code](https://godbolt.org/z/MUJ-Ro), it seems to be huge. Also I wonder what RAM it will use.

I have to work with a C++14 compliant compiler, so :

1. What is the best manner to replace this legacy C code with C++14?
2. What is the best manner to replace this legacy C code with C++17?

`constexpr` may be a part of the answer...

[edit] I don't want to *replace* the C code, but adapt it to have a function that takes an int as a parameter and returns another int. It is running on a small embedded system so I want it to be as tight as possible (in terms of flash & RAM).

Comment: it is not quite clear how your second is a replacement for the first. The first merely defines some preprocessor symbols but there is no index (only in the names)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using c++17 changing

```
const std::array<int, 32> iocon_index = [](){
    std::array<int, 32> buf;
```

to

```
constexpr std::array<int, 32> iocon_index = []() {
    std::array<int, 32> buf { };
```

seems to solve the assembly size issue (-O2 and -Os)

In c++14 you can use a constexpr function instead of a lambda to initialize the array.

EDIT:
`std::array` is not `constexpr` modifiable in c++14. This is a dirty way to circumvent that issue

```
std::array<int, 32> buf { };
const auto& as_const = buf;

const_cast<int&>(as_const[17]) = 0; //operator[](size_type) const is constexpr
const_cast<int&>(as_const[13]) = 1; //but not operator[](size_type)
...
```

EDIT2:
To make it more readable one can do

```
struct array_assign
{
    constexpr
    array_assign(std::array<int, 32>& arr) :
        arr(arr)
    { }

    constexpr int& operator[](std::size_t idx)
    {
        return const_cast<int&>(this->arr[idx]);
    }

    const std::array<int, 32>& arr;
};
```

and then

```
std::array<int, 32> buf2 { };
array_assign buf(buf2);

buf[17] = 0;
buf[13] = 1;
buf[12] = 2;
...
return buf2;
```

Comment: thanks! For those who want to see the C++17 version: [https://godbolt.org/z/btrke-](https://godbolt.org/z/btrke-)

Comment: however I can't make it work with C++14 due to [] operator of std::array : [https://godbolt.org/z/X8-cdq](https://godbolt.org/z/X8-cdq). Any idea why?

Comment: Edited the post to reflect that `std::array::operator[](...)` is not `constexpr` in c++14

Comment: Thanks for the update. If we balance code readability and assembly output, then I think it is better to go for @code_fodder solution for C++14 and best to use yours for C++17.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a lambda you can just create a constexpr:

```
#include <utility>
int icon_index(int pio_index)
{

    constexpr std::pair<int, int> map_items[] = {
        {10, 1},
        {11, 15},
        {12, 3},
        {13, 32},
        {14, 9},
        {15, 8},
        {16, 9},
        {17, 7},
        {18, 6},
        {19, 5},
        {45, 4}
    };

    for (auto item : map_items)
    {
        if (pio_index == item.first)
        {
            return item.second;
        }
    }

    return 0; /// not found
}
```

I imagine you can also use std::array - but this is a mapping that you can use any pair of types. Using constexpr means it is generated at compile time.

### Updated:

```
#include <utility>

constexpr int find_item(int idx)
{
    std::pair<int, int> map_items[] = {
        {10, 1},
        {11, 15},
        {12, 3},
        {13, 32},
        {14, 9},
        {15, 8},
        {16, 9},
        {17, 7},
        {18, 6},
        {19, 5},
        {45, 4}
    };

    for (auto item : map_items)
    {
        if (idx == item.first)
        return item.second;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int i = find_item(12);
    return i; // returns 3
}
```

Comment: It is a great solution but the output assembly code seems to be bigger!

Comment: @Victor ah, well, most of that is the for loop! - I figured your main issue was storage of the mapping. You could make the find loop into a const expr - this gives less lines of assembler - see updated...

Comment: The above code compiles into about 11 lines of assembler and returns 3: https://godbolt.org/z/fPeuJf

Comment: why did you change the good looking `for each` to an ugly `while`?

Comment: @Mestkon I don't think you can do for loops in constexpr? ... at least I thought you can - I recall reading something about that a while back, but honestly I did not try... will quickly try now...

Comment: @Mestkon oh, you are right! - you can do for loop: https://godbolt.org/z/bjhjfm (updated answer again)

Comment: In c++11 you are quite limited to what you can do in `constexpr` functions, no loops for example. c++14 relaxed many of those constraints.

Comment: @Mestkon yeah I think I got confused by that thanks :) ... its a confusing time switching between compiler versions :o

Comment: Last thing : the `return 0;` line worries me. I would like to throw an error but it seems to be impossible in the constexpr...

Comment: @Victor with valid input: https://godbolt.org/z/42ufHH, with invalid input: https://godbolt.org/z/RG263m - note the second one gives compile error becuase constexpr is evaluated at compile time - so this is what you want.